# Android exo player instance not working properly?

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer, android-videoview, exoplayer

I am using ExoPLayer to play video in android. Suppose I have two ExoPlayer instance. I initialize first player and then assign it to second player, then I release first player. When I release the first player it also stops the second player. I want to continue playing videos with second player. Hope you understand. Below is the sample code...

```
 private fun switchParameters() {
    // SimpleExoPlayer instance 
    currentPlayer = temporaryPlayer
    // PlayerView instance
    playerView = temporaryPlayerView
    
    if (temporaryPlayer != null) {
        temporaryPlayer!!.release()
        temporaryPlayer = null
        mediaSource = null
        temporaryPlayerView!!.onPause()
        temporaryPlayerView = null
    }
}
```

When I release temporaryPlayer , currentPlayer stops working. I don't want this.

Comment: because it points to the same memory location.

Comment: How can I prevent this?